# Get image choosen full path while ulpoading a image

Tags: php, image, file-upload, path, laravel-6

Here i want to get the image path of the selected image where it resides.i had wrote `$file_path = $file->getRealPath();` and its shows like this `"C:\wamp64\tmp\phpEFBC.tmp"` but what i need is the folder name where image resides like this `C:\Users\dev\Desktop\abc`.Is there any way to get that in laravel.how can we change the  `upload_tmp_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"` of `php.ini` to get the desired result

Comment: Is there any hint?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. The file you're looking at appears to be located at `C:\wamp64\tmp\phpEFBC.tmp`. Why would it be anywhere else? If you're after the location of the file on the client machine (ie the _"uploader"_), you're out of luck. Neither PHP or JavaScript have access to that data